# Websphere trust.p12 vs cacert store

Tags: ssl, websphere, spring-integration, truststore

We are using Spring Integration is connect to https/ssl external system. After Adding certificate using the external host and port 443, and Retrieve from port. The certificate exists.

But the application keeps failing

```
>     ERROR 2886 --- [ebContainer : 1] c.i.w.w.servlet.ServletWrapper           : SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause
> dispatcherServlet:
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error:
> com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed:
> java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl
> could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
>             java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=ODC somest Root CA - G1, O=ODC sonst, C=TR is
> not trusted; internal cause is:
>             java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path
> building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
> PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal
> cause is:
>             java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=ODC somest Root CA - G1, O=ODC sonst, C=PR is
> not trusted; internal cause is:
>             java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
```

If I run keytool and import certificate into cacert, the application works. But this solution is not accepted by maintenance team, as it does not show up in websphere console.
Is there anything that I can change in spring integration request
 So can I ask anyone to help me understand the problem and the fix.

**UPDATE**

> /srv/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore
>   /srv/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/K1Node01Cell/nodes/K1Node01/trust.p12
>   -storepass WebAS -storetype PKCS12

shows the certificate entry...not sure how to confirm if it is complete or incorrect

**Question:**

> Should Retrieve from Port update cacert file? cacert is inside websphere jre security, whereas trust.p12 is inside profile/../nodes

**UPDATE 2**:

I've enabled tracing and see below logs. Is it spring that is trying to look into cacerts...or it is normal, because it is part of JRE used by WebSphere

```
> [18-2-19 13:44:59:154 ] 00000063 SystemOut     O 2019-02-18
> 13:44:59.153  INFO 30426 --- [ver.startup : 0]
> pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path
> [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json>
> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
> [18-2-19 13:44:59:826 ] 00000063 SystemOut     O keyStore is:
> /srv/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
> [18-2-19 13:44:59:826 ] 00000063 SystemOut     O keyStore type is: jks
> [18-2-19 13:44:59:827 ] 00000063 SystemOut     O keyStore provider is:
> [18-2-19 13:44:59:827 ] 00000063 SystemOut     O init keystore
> [18-2-19 13:44:59:906 ] 00000063 SystemOut     O SSLContextImpl: 
> Using X509ExtendedKeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.ay [18-2-19 13:44:59:908 ]
> 00000063 SystemOut     O trustStore is:
> /srv/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you did perform a node synchronization and restart the server(s) the app is deployed to, right? I believe that's required for applications to pick up the new certs in the trust store.

Comment: I don't know about node synchronization, but  restart was performed many times [after every small change]

Comment: Have you add also the root certificate and intermediate certificates  from CA?

Comment: Since you're talking about the console, I assume this is Traditional WAS rather than Liberty? And the certificate mentioned in that error *is* the one you see in WebSphere trust store signer certs? Which trust store did you retrieve into? My guess would be that the one you retrieved it into is not the one being checked; I've seen that occur before.

Comment: @dbreaux  yes traditional was server. only 1 trust store - defaulttruststore in our WAS. How can I debug where application is looking?

Comment: Well, if there's only one, that's probably not the issue. I was thinking of a WAS ND where there are CellDefaultTrustStore, NodeDefaultTrustStore, etc. In our case, at least one of the error messages listed the actual file name it was looking in.

Comment: If it works when you add cert to cacerts, then you probably incorrectly create SSL connection, overriding WebSphere defaults. Make sure you dont have any code like this `Security.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");` in your application. Also make sure that if certificate is not self sign, you have all parent certs added to the truststore.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to just your last question, no, Retrieve from Port should not update `cacerts`. It should update a file like the `trust.p12` file you mention.

However, your path indicates that you do have an ND environment, with Cell and Nodes. And that you've imported into the NodeDefaultTrustStore. We always import into CellDefaultTrustStore instead. You might try that?

Comment: NodeDefaultTrustStore  has Managemnt scope (cell):...:(node):... I don't see cellDefaultTrustStore

Comment: Hmmm... is the Node part of a Cell, but there are no `cell:...` scoped key/trust stores at all? If so, the issue could be related to that, maybe.

Comment: sorry if dots confused you. I used ... instead of name for node and cell. I can mask names and update tomorrow

Comment: No, I understood that, I was doing the same thing. I'm asking whether you don't have any cell scoped key/trust stores at all? You only have cell&node scoped ones?

Answer (score 0):

I followed IBM link and used useSystemProperties(). This will use the certificate inside the websphere, else it will look for certificate in the Server Java

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/394270/im-using-an-apache-httpclient-to-make-an-outbound/

HttpClient theClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor()).build();